# How to solve logistic regression using gradient descent in octave?

Tags: machine-learning, octave, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I am learning Machine Learning course from coursera from Andrews Ng. I have written a code for logistic regression in octave. But, it is not working. Can someone help me?

I have taken the dataset from the following link:
[Titanic survivors](https://www.kaggle.com/heptapod/titanic)

Here is my code:

```
pkg load io;

[An, Tn, Ra, limits] = xlsread("~/ML/ML Practice/dataset/train_and_test2.csv", "Sheet2", "A2:H1000");

# As per CSV file we are reading columns from 1 to 7. 8-th column is Survived, which is what we are going to predict
X = [An(:, [1:7])];

Y = [An(:, 8)];

X = horzcat(ones(size(X,1), 1), X);

# Initializing theta values as zero for all
#theta = zeros(size(X,2),1);
theta = [-3;1;1;-3;1;1;1;1];
learningRate = -0.00021;
#learningRate = -0.00011;

# Step 1: Calculate Hypothesis
function g_z = estimateHypothesis(X, theta)
  z = theta' * X';
  z = z';

  e_z = -1 * power(2.72, z);
  denominator = 1.+e_z;
  g_z = 1./denominator;
endfunction

# Step 2: Calculate Cost function
function cost = estimateCostFunction(hypothesis, Y)
  log_1 = log(hypothesis);
  log_2 = log(1.-hypothesis);

  y1 = Y;
  term_1 = y1.*log_1;

  y2 = 1.-Y;
  term_2 = y2.*log_2;

  cost = term_1 + term_2;
  cost = sum(cost);

  # no.of.rows
  m = size(Y, 1);
  cost = -1 * (cost/m); 

endfunction

# Step 3: Using gradient descent I am updating theta values
function updatedTheta = updateThetaValues(_X, _Y, _theta, _hypothesis, learningRate)
  #s1 = _X * _theta;
  #s2 = s1 - _Y;
  #s3 = _X' * s2;

  # no.of.rows
  #m = size(_Y, 1);

  #s4 = (learningRate * s3)/m;

  #updatedTheta = _theta - s4;

  s1 = _hypothesis - _Y;

  s2 = s1 .* _X;
  s3 = sum(s2);

  # no.of.rows
  m = size(_Y, 1);

  s4 = (learningRate * s3)/m;
  updatedTheta = _theta .- s4';
endfunction

costVector = [];
iterationVector = [];
for i = 1:1000
  # Step 1
  hypothesis = estimateHypothesis(X, theta);
  #disp("hypothesis");
  #disp(hypothesis);

  # Step 2
  cost = estimateCostFunction(hypothesis, Y);
  costVector = vertcat(costVector, cost);
  #disp("Cost");
  #disp(cost);

  # Step 3 - Updating theta values
  theta = updateThetaValues(X, Y, theta, hypothesis, learningRate);

  iterationVector = vertcat(iterationVector, i);
endfor

function plotGraph(iterationVector, costVector)
  plot(iterationVector, costVector);
  ylabel('Cost Function');
  xlabel('Iteration');  
endfunction

plotGraph(iterationVector, costVector);
```

This is the graph I am getting when I am plotting against no.of.iterations and cost function.

[image: Logistic regression graph]

I am tired by adjusting theta values and learning rate. Can someone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I have removed the features with column name "zero" and "id" from the CSV file.

Comment: Please do not use the comments space for this kind of additional info - edit & update your post instead. Also, you should have added the `octave` tag (added for you this time).

Answer (score 0):

I have done a mathematical error. I should have used either power(2.72, -z) or exp(-z). Instead I have used as -1 * power(2.72, z). Now, I'm getting a proper curve.

[image: Logistic Regression Cost function curve]

Thanks.